# /bin/bash shell (macOS) throwing `-bash: declare: -A: invalid option` error message at shell start

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, shell, fish

I briefly changed my default shell on macOS Catalina (10.15.1) to Fish, following the steps in [Fish's documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#switching-to-fish).

First, I executed `> echo /usr/local/bin/fish | sudo tee -a /etc/shells` followed by `> chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish`. After, I realized I only needed to use one of these commands, not both, but oh well. What's done is done.

Later, I decided to switch back to bash, so I ran the commands in reverse (according to Fish's instructions for reverting) First, `> echo /bin/bash | sudo tee -a /etc/shells` followed by `> chsh -s /bin/bash`

When I reloaded the shell using Bash, I received the following error.

```
-bash: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
-bash: complete: -D: invalid option
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [-X filterpat] [-F function] [-C command] [name ...]

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

This error did not appear before changing the shell to Fish and then back to Bash, and I didn't edit any .bashrc or .bash_profile files before changing the shell back to Bash. Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: You only need to (/should) use the `echo /path/to/shell | sudo tee -a /etc/shells` command *if the shell you want is not already listed in /etc/shells*. `/usr/local/bin/fish` almost certainly wasn't, but `/bin/bash` was. You should check to see what's already there before adding others (or the same ones again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The */bin/bash* that ships with macOS Catalina is really old (version 3.2.57) and does not support `declare -A`. Presumably you had been using the Homebrew version installed as */usr/local/bin/bash* which does support `declare -A`. So assuming you have a */usr/local/bin/bash* simply ensure that is present in */etc/shells* then run `chpass -s /usr/local/bin/bash`.

P.S., You can view your current user profile, which includes your default shell, by simply typing `chpass` with no options.